# How to use mappedBy with more than one value JPA

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.1, mappedby

I have 2 tables:
Currency and Rate

The currency's primary key is referenced by the inputCurrency and outputCurrency foreigh keys in the Rate.

How can I map these in order to cascadeALL?

I tried in Rate (the table that contains the foreigh keys)

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "INPUT_CURRENCY")
private Currency inputCurrency;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "OUTPUT_CURRENCY")
private Currency ouputCurrency;
```

But if I delete an item from currency It results a primary key violation.I can't remove a Currency becouse it is referenced by inputCurrency or outputCurrency in Rate.

If I want to annotate the list of rates in Currency, how can I say mappedBy = "inputCurrency" and "outputCurrency" ?

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy ="inputCurrency,outputCurrency")
List<Rate> rates;
```

Comment: clearly you cannot use mappedBy with multiple values because it makes no sense. "mappedBy" = "where is this bidirectional relation stored" ... and it can't be stored in multiple places!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is using two list of rates in Currency: one for the fk inputCurrency
and another for the fk outputCurrency

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy ="inputCurrency")
List<Rate> ratesIC;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy ="outputCurrency")
List<Rate> ratesOC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can settle with two collections:

`List<Rate> inputRate;`

`List<Rate> outputRate;`

Each with a corresponding `mappedBy`

and a third `@Transient List<Rate> rates;`

You can use a `@PostLoad` event to unite the two persistent lists into the transient one.

And similarly, when adding/removing elements to one of the persistent lists, make sure to add/remove from the joint list.

Comment: Thank you for sugestion.